# How to duplicate a classic theme in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

What I did. I copied a classic theme. Rename a main folder, rename values in translations. Add my own preview.png and of course changed theme.yml. Then I uploaded a ZIP to my store. Now I see the classic theme twice. Why ?

Kind regards

Comment: i've the same problem, did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

- Copy the classic folder to another folder, for example "test".
- Edit file test/config/theme.yml and change "name" field to match the folder name you have created, in this case "test". Name field and folder name must be the same. Save the file.
- Go to backoffice and reload theme page.

Where is the problem? In the moment you refresh the backoffice, presta creates a folder in /config/themes with the name of your new theme created before. Inside it, it creates a file called "shop1.json"  (configuration for shop number 1). Here you will find some configuration that came from the original theme.yml file.
If you refresh backoffice before modifying theme.yml, presta creates that file and if later you modify theme.yml it doesn't modify again shop1.json, so you won't see changes ever.
The solution is to delete that .json file and refresh again backoffice to regenerate the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to archive your theme. It would be enough to copy your **`classic`** theme in the same folder themes. Rename your **`classic`** folder to **`classic_new`**(for example) and change a field **`name`** in **`theme.yml`** from **`classic`** to **`classic_new`**(also you can change all related information if you wish). And then you will see your classic_new theme in the admin panel.

Comment: But if I do like You said I have two themes with the same name "Classic" even when I change name in theme.yml

Comment: Yes. When I click to use this theme (new classic) I have error: [ThemeRepository] Theme configuration file not found for theme at `D:\laragon\www\domain.com/themes/classic/config/theme.yml` I dont know why I have classic in this path. In config file I have another name. The folder name of my new classic theme.

Comment: It's very weird. Can you share your theme.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

After click on "use this theme" button and have error, I just change **theme_name=classic** with MyThemeName, from the bar and then press enter.

`https://.......&action=enableTheme&theme_name=classic`

After that, was installed correctly and I try to switch with the classic one and my theme was there ready to install again.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue, check the file config/themes/your_theme/shop1.json
It may have the wrong information.